# Commands for Tx Power, Rx Power and RSSI

Tags: bluetooth

I have a looked far and wide, on the Bluez.org and Android developer forum, http://developer.android.com/resources/community-groups.html however have been unable to find the solution to what I am looking for.

Could someone please assist me to find out what are the commands to modify the Values of TX Power, and get the valued of Received Power (RX Power) and RSSI.

Much Appreciate it.

Daud

Answer (score 0):

There are no standard or Public APIs to set the transmit power, typically the interface is given by the Bluetooth chip vendor via custom driver APIs to be able to set the maximum transmit power of a device.

For the RSSI you can get this value from device discovery - In android ACTION_FOUND intent has android.bluetooth.device.extra.RSSI which can contain RSSI for the remote device.